# VS2012 Model First EF: CSDL, MSL, SSDL. System cannot find the file specified MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I get errors on build stating 'The System cannot find the file specified' for each of the 3 metadata files 'CSDL, MSDL, SSDL'

Able to generate model from DB fine, connection string fine. Reinstalled the correct connector just fine and MYSQL as a provider appears fine in VS2012.

The 'Metadata Artifact Processing' propery on the model is set to 'Embed in Output Assembly' as instructed.

Out of ideas and hours to keep hunting, would really appreciate a fix here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening as I had a build script that deleted these metadata files as a result.

Sorry, my bad.